# How to have some subviews in UIScrollView never zoom?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, zooming, subview

I have a polygon view in a scrollview. When the user zooms the scrollview, the polygon is magnified, but so are the handles on each of its vertices (when selected).

How can I make sure that the handles size stay constant whatever the zoom factor?

The handles are subviews of the polygon. I would be willing to consider a different approach if that made it any simpler.

Thanks a lot

JD

Answer (score 0):

how about grabbing the zoom level of your parent uiscrollview and passing it into your polygon object and applying the opposite scaling to the handles?  So if you are at 200% with the uiscrollview, downsize the handles to 50%

or

you could make your polygon uiview auto resizable in width/height and manually code the zoom process responding to your uiscrollview by changing the size of your polygon, not scaling it.

Comment: I thought about your first approach, which I believe is likely to succeed with the least effort. I don't like the second approach, especially because the polygon is far from being the only shape in the scroll view. The first approach incurs a significant cost each time the view is zoomed, as in my case I may have dozens of subviews to scale, but I don't think there is any way to avoid that cost.